# How to distribute parameterized pytest for testing in azure pieplines as different jobs

Tags: python, azure-pipelines, pytest

I have a pytest file that has 1 test and and it is parameterized such that in total there are 100 different tests.

I created a pipeline with 2 parallel jobs but when I start the jobs, both the jobs run all the 100 tests individually.

What happens:

```
**Job 1
  ----Test 1
  ----Test 2
  ...
  ----Test 100

Job 2
  ----Test 1
  ----Test 2
  ...
  ----Test 100**
```

I want the tests to be evenly distributed between these two jobs.

What is required:

```
**Job 1
  ----Test 1
  ----Test 2
  ...
  ----Test 50

Job 2
  ----Test 51
  ----Test 52
  ...
  ----Test 100**
```

Here is the pipeline code

```
jobs:
- job: 'QA_Pipeline'
  strategy:
    parallel: 2
  pool: vm-dev-pool
  
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.8'

  - script:  |
       pip install pytest
       pip install pytest-xdist
    displayName: 'Install modules'

  - script: |
      pytest  -n=2 --capture=tee-sys ./test_smokeTests.py --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml
    displayName: 'Run Smoke Tests'
```

Here is the test  file

```
class Test_SmokeTests:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param1,param2",
                             [
                                 (a1,b1),
                                 (a2,b2),
                                 ...
                                 ...
                                 (a100,b100)

                             ]
                             )
    def test_smokeTest(self, param1,param2):
        print("param1 - ", param1)
        print("param2 - ", param2)
```

**NOTE:** I have been able to distribute tests within a single Job using the pytest-xdist lib. That works but splitting the tests between different Jobs is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this.

First I gather all the tests and save them to a text file from the command line

```
pytest  --collect-only -q  > c:/dev/abc.txt
```

Then in the pipeline, I read the file with all the tests and then slice them in smaller groups based on the number of jobs.

```
$tests = Get-Content .\SmokeTestList.txt

$totalAgents = [int]$Env:SYSTEM_TOTALJOBSINPHASE
$agentNumber = [int]$Env:SYSTEM_JOBPOSITIONINPHASE
$testCount = $tests.Count

if ($totalAgents -eq 0) {
    $totalAgents = 1
}
if (!$agentNumber -or $agentNumber -eq 0) {
    $agentNumber = 1
}

$testsToRun= @()

For ($i=$agentNumber; $i -le $testCount;) {
    $file = $tests[$i-1]
    $testsToRun = $testsToRun + $file
    Write-Host "Added $file"
    $i = $i + $totalAgents
 }


$testFiles = $testsToRun -Join " "
```

More info can be found here
https://github.com/DanielAtKrypton/ParallelTestingSample-Python/blob/master/DistributeTests.ps1

Pipelie looks like this

```
jobs:
- job: 'QA_Pipeline'
  strategy:
    parallel: 2
  pool: vm-dev-pool
  
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.8'

  - script:  |
       pip install pytest
       pip install pytest-xdist
    displayName: 'Install modules'

  - powershell: ./DistributeTests.ps1 
       displayName: 'Distribute tests'

  - script: |
      pytest  -n=2 --capture=tee-sys $(pytestfiles) --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml
    displayName: 'Run Smoke Tests'
```